# undetected_chromedriver is unable to reopen Chrome window if it was closed/quit

Tags: python, undetected-chromedriver

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-popup-blocking')
...

if step == "0" and not stop_execution:
        while True:
            try:
                driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
                driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)
                new_title = f"ABC"
                driver.execute_script(f"document.title = '{new_title}';")

                # Ensure we kill the old webdriver
                kill_old_webdriver()
                save_pid(driver.service.process.pid)

            except:
                # close the browser and try again
                driver.quit()
                continue


    elif step == "1" and not stop_execution:
        while True:
            try:
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
                # Open a new tab and switch focus to it
                driver.execute_script('window.open();')
                driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
                
                time.sleep(1)
                driver.get("https://google.com")
                time.sleep(1)
```

With normal Selenium, if step 0 was executed (again), it will open a new Chrome window and killed the previous. But with Undetected ChromeDriver it wont do the same. It wont open anything at all.